# What's the difference between "ask" and "be asked"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, present-tense

I saw this sentence:

> This could **be asked** on Web Applications.

I thought i can replace this sentence with following sentence:

> You could **ask** this on Web Applications.

but they may have differences. What's the difference between "ask" and "be asked"?

Comment: Rephrase: You could ask this on Web Applications

Comment: Yes, something like "This dialogue could ask users to select their date of birth" would be acceptable but it would not work in the first sentence. As written after the edit, your two sentences are synonymous.

Comment: It's just the difference between the active and passive voices.  Active: You *ask* the question.  Passive: The question *is asked* (or *could be asked*) by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer:

> I ask you a question. [active voice]
>   You are asked a question by me. [passive voice]

That is the difference.

> This could be asked [by you] on Web Applications.
>   You could ask this on Web Applications.

Unless it is necessary to the meaning, try to use active voice rather than passive voice.

> The boys ate the apples.
>   The apples were eaten by the boys.